# Split numbers with thousands separator using stream editor (sed)

Tags: sed

I want to insert periods as thousands separators into numbers using `sed`. How can I do that?

Sample input/output: `29371923471239` should become `29.371.923.471.239`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo "29371923471239" | sed -r ':A;s|([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})|\1,\2|g;t A'
29,371,923,471,239
```

This works by  splitting the number into two parts, the last 3 digits and everything else. It then adds a `,` to the end of everything else and branches back to the start. You can see this working with

```
echo "29371923471239" | sed -r ':A;s|([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})|\1,\2|g'
29371923471,239
```

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_007.html

`sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'`

`echo "981273981723" | sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'
981,273,981,723`

Comment: An explanation is good for the benefit of your answer, not a reference to a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

**USE GHC-ONELINERS FOR A GREAT GOOD**

```
$> echo -n 29371923471239 | ghc -e "import Data.List.Split" -e "putStrLn . reverse . intercalate \".\" . splitEvery 3 . reverse =<< getContents"
29.371.923.471.239
```

!